# Batch file script does not work as I believe it should

Tags: batch-file, cmd, runtime-error

I need help with a batch script that checks if the process RainbowSix_BE.exe is working. If so, check whether another process is started; if not start it.

```batch-file
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions
:loop
tasklist /fi "imagename eq RainbowSix_BE.exe" |find ":" > nul
IF errorlevel 0 goto Start
IF errorlevel 1 goto Stop

:Start
tasklist|find /i "wallpaper.exe" >NUL if errorlevel 1 WallPaperPlugin.exe
goto loop

:Stop
taskkill /F /IM wallpaper.exe
goto loop
```

---

[progress]

So I got very close to solving the issue this way but after the start function starts the file the next time the loop runs I don't know why it closes the wallpaper.exe even if Rainbow is not open

```
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions
set EXE=RainbowSix_BE.exe
set MEXE=wallpaper.exe
:Loop
FOR /F %%x IN ('tasklist /NH /FI "IMAGENAME eq %EXE%"') DO IF %%x == %EXE% 
goto Stop


:Start
FOR /F %%x IN ('tasklist /NH /FI "IMAGENAME eq %MEXE%"') DO IF %%x == %MEXE% 
goto Stop
Start ""  "C:\Users\CrySteRz\Desktop\PC\Wesch\WallPaperPlugin.exe"
timeout /t 5 /nobreak >nul
Goto Loop


:Stop
FOR /F %%x IN ('tasklist /NH /FI "IMAGENAME eq %MEXE%"') DO IF %%x == %MEXE% 
taskkill.exe /F /IM %MEXE%
timeout /t 5 /nobreak >nul
Goto Loop
```

Comment: I think replacement variables are processed for each line, before the logic for that line is run, so for `tasklist|find /i "wallpaper.exe" >NUL if errorlevel 1 WallPaperPlugin.exe`, the errorlevel is whatever value was set by the previous line, not the `tasklist` result on that line. Try `help setlocal` and take a look at how EnableDelayedExpansion works, or just put that if statement on the next line.

Comment: You also have the problem that you fall-through from the `:loop` block into the `:Start` block, which could lead to a lot of excessive CPU and drive thrashing. Your script should either `exit` at some point, or you should introduce a delay in there somewhere.

Comment: `if errorlevel 1 WallPaperPlugin.exe` should not be on the same line as the `tasklist` command under the `:Start` label, which should look more like the version you used under the `:loop `label anyhow. However you've also got an issue under that label too, which is easiliy fixed by deleting the line `IF errorlevel 0 goto Start`

Comment: You should probably reread the help file for the `IF` command. `IF ERRORLEVEL 0` means if the error level is zero or greater. It doesn't mean it equals zero.

Comment: You have not explained to anybody how you "believe it should" be working. You have also not explained to anybody, what is supposed to happen you run it, or what exactly does happen. We expect to see some sort of debugging information, so for instance you can monitor the `cmd.exe` output as you don't have `echo`ing turned off, and you can also monitor things in the Task Manager GUI. Also you haven't explained how you're invoking this script, whether there's any more code above it, ownership/privilege details, or any other potentially useful information we may need to assist you with your issue.

Comment: The code is converted to exe and invoked at the startup of the pc, and it should do exactly this               If RainbowSix_BE.exe is running and wallpaper.exe is running, kill wallpaper.exe. If RainbowSix_BE.exe is not running and wallpaper.exe is not running, start the executable file WallPaperPlugin.exe

Comment: No code is being "converted to exe", all that is happening is your batch file is being packaged inside a self extracting executable. When you run it, the batch file is being extracted to a temporary, probably hidden location, and being run before it is deleted. In order to assist with that, you'd need to fully explain what is being packaged, using what tool, what the packaging settings were, exactly how it is being invoked, and all other pertinent details. Please note however, that this site assist you with your code, not with the use of software, for that you should really ask the developers.

Comment: Batch is not a free-format language. An `if` statement must be immediately followed on the same physical line by a single statement, a compound statement (sequence of statements separated by `&`) or a `code block` (a parenthesised sequence of statements). If an `else` clause is used, then the `if` must be followed by a `code block`, the `else` must appear on the same line as the `)` and then `else` follows the rule for `if`. If a `code block` if used, it must have its `(` appear on the same physical line as the `if/else`.keyword. The `else` keyword must appear on the same line as the `)`

Answer (score 0):

As long as your actions were correct for your error levels, the following would be a little more like it:

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions

:Loop
%SystemRoot%\System32\tasklist.exe /Fi "ImageName Eq RainbowSix_BE.exe"^
 | %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe ":" 1> NUL
If ErrorLevel 1 GoTo Stop

:Start
%SystemRoot%\System32\tasklist.exe /Fi "ImageName Eq wallpaper.exe"^
 | %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe ":" 1> NUL
If ErrorLevel 1 Start "" "F:\ull\PathTo\WallPaperPlugin.exe"
%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 3 /NoBreak 1> NUL
GoTo Loop

:Stop
%SystemRoot%\System32\tasklist.exe /Fi "ImageName Eq wallpaper.exe"^
 | %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe ":" 1> NUL
If Not ErrorLevel 1 (
    %SystemRoot%\System32\taskkill.exe /F /IM wallpaper.exe 1> NUL
)
%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 3 /NoBreak 1> NUL
GoTo Loop
```

I doubt very much that `WallPaperPlugin.exe` is in a directory listed under `%Path%`, *and even if it was, you shouldn't be assuming that `%Path%` isn't corrupted*. I've therefore used a fake path to show you that you should be using a full path. If you were simply assuming it to be in the current directory, you shouldn't be, because you clearly have not defined that anywhere in your script. If it is in the same directory as the batch file, you could however use `"%~dp0WallPaperPlugin.exe"` instead. Do not forget to change it before your run the script.

Comment: I tried your advice but the batch just seems do to nothing in whatever conditions applied to it, isn't there a more consistent way of doin it?Thx

Comment: How about you tell us what it is supposed to do. This  was written to do what your code was written to do, but without the coding issues. So what happens in it, is this: If `RainbowSix_BE.exe` is running and `wallpaper.exe` is running, kill `wallpaper.exe`. If `RainbowSix_BE.exe` is not running and `wallpaper.exe` is not running, start the exectuable file `WallPaperPlugin.exe`. Of course you must have the permissions to kill `wallpaper.exe`, and to start `WallPaperPlugin.exe`. We also expect you to debug what is happening, so remove `@Echo off` and monitor the output, and even Task Manager.

Comment: That is exactly what my program is supposed to do but it's been 2 days now and when i get something working something else is not, i'm going to keep going, removing the echo off as you say, thx for the advices

Comment: I've just read your comment under the main question, and that is irrelevant to my answer and the issues you had in your submitted batch script code. My answer is correct, it will do what it is supposed to do, as long as the location of `WallPaperPlugin.exe` is correctly defined, and the invoking user has sufficient permissions. Please do not test my script after packaging it inside an exe, test it exactly as posted, with no additions or modifications. I do not, and will not support applications which can corrupt scripts, modify permissions, and current directories etc.

Comment: It seems that the only part not working is the wallpaperplugin start, the loop is doing good

Comment: Well @IonutBlidaru, I do not know where `WallPaperPlugin.exe` is, so you have to provide the fully qualified absolute path to it yourself. As you are intending to package this inside some pointless and waste of time executable, when it is run, you will have no real idea what the working directory is, or the execuatbles location in relation to it. That is why you must use the full path. It is also important that you do not remove, or adjust any of the doublequoting I have used on that line only the path within them.

Comment: I did put the path and im absolutely sure i put it the right way, but it still does not want to start the exe file

Comment: @IonutBlidaru, is `WallPaperPlugin.exe` also packed inside your exe file? and is it another packaged exe file itself? If its isn't either of those things, then the issue is with that file, not with the code I've provided. If it is just packaged with the batch file, then it will likely be unpacked to the same location as it at runtime. In that case you should be using `If ErrorLevel 1 Start "" "%~dp0WallPaperPlugin.exe"`, as I've already advised, if not then you need to give us more information. Only you are sat in front of your PC, and only you know its location and/or execute permissions!